# How to stop display from blanking on Ubuntu Server 15.10?

Tags: command-line, server, suspend

I can't figure this out anywhere. I want to have the display for my server running 24/7 for monitoring reasons, but it keeps blanking after so long. I've already tried `consoleblank=0`, and it didn't work. Again, I'm running Ubuntu Server 15.10. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I know it's a silly question, but did you execute `sudo update-grub` after you added `consoleblank=0` to grub?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I found a solution. I just added `setterm -blank 0 -powersave off` to my .bashrc file.